# How to format DateTime in params in Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

Sometimes we need to accept `DateTime` from client:

```
params do
   requires :time_to_arrive, type: DateTime, allow_blank: false
end
```

If we write in console `DateTime.now`, it will give it in this format by default:

```
Sat, 16 Apr 2016 09:59:26 +0600
```

Is it possible to specify the format for accepting `DateTime` in grape?

Comment: You means specify it in view or where?

Comment: @Ilya I mean specify it in `params` section, because client that will make requests is not ruby based application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating your Custom Type:

```
class MyDateTime
  attr_reader :value
  def initialize(datetime)
    @value = datetime
  end

  def self.parse(value)
    my_date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
    dt = DateTime.strptime(value, my_date_format)
    new(dt)
  end
end


requires :time_to_arrive, type: MyDateTime, allow_blank: false
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the `coerce_with` option:

```
params do
   requires :time_to_arrive, type: DateTime, coerce_with: DateTime.method(:iso8601), allow_blank: false
end
```

Also when calling your API you can specify iso8601 format with `your_date_time_var.iso8601`.